# Iterating through array of hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, hash, iteration

I have a hash like so.

```
h = {"name"=>"United States House of Representatives TX-21",
     "divisionId"=>"ocd-division/country:us/state:tx/cd:21",
     "levels"=>["country"],
     "roles"=>["legislatorLowerBody"],
     "officials"=>[{"name"=>"Lamar Smith",
                    "address"=>[
                      {"line1"=>"2409 rayburn house office building",
                       "city"=>"washington",
                       "state"=>"DC",
                       "zip"=>"20515"
                      }
                    ],
                    "party"=>"Republican",
                    "phones"=>["(202) 225-4236"],
                    "urls"=>["http://lamarsmith.house.gov/"],
                    "photoUrl"=>"http://...",
                    "channels"=>[
                      {"type"=>"Facebook", "id"=>"LamarSmithTX21"},
                      {"type"=>"Twitter", "id"=>"LamarSmithTX21"},
                      {"type"=>"YouTube", "id"=>"lamarsmithtexas21"}
                    ]
                   }
                  ]
    }
```

I am attempting to do an `if` statement that will push this array into another array called `@nationalOffices` if the `levels` hash == `country`. The problem is the value of the levels hash is an array. I am not sure how to do this. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I reformatted your hash (not array) so that it can be comprehended, but I did nothing with your last paragraph because I do not understand it. When you give an example, you should do three things: 1. reduce the size of the example to the minimum necessary to make your point; 2. show your expected or desired output; and 3. assign a variable to each input object (e.g., `h = { ... }` as I did above), so that readers can refer to those variables (here `h`) in answers and comments without having to define them.

Comment: You are using the word array in a confusing way here. Is this one hash of many inside an array? When you say "push this array into another array" do you mean push this _hash_ into `@nationalOffices`? Give more context on the actual data you're working with.

Answer (score 0):

You'd access it by getting deeper into the hash e.g. `array[0]["levels"]` . You'd probably have to save this API response in a variable and then work your way into it.
If you want learn more about hashes and arrays, this is a pretty good tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_hashes.htm

Answer (score 0):

@nationalOffices << my_array if levels == country ? : #else statement goes here